# JQuery how to pass data to click without onclick?

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have problem to pass data to function from blade template to click. I don;t want to use onclik. I have a global variable passed to my blade tempate like : oreder and after blick on button I need to pass this data. HEre is my code:

```
 <button class="btn" id="someButton">Some text</button>
```

And here jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#someButton').on('click', function (here I need to pass global data from blade like : order->id etc) {});
})
```

Is there a possibility to do this?

Comment: so which event you want to use for this attempt.ie hover,action,blur

Comment: Use `data-*` attributes

Comment: In jQuery? Like this? $(document).ready(function () {

$('#someButton').on('click', function (data-order->id etc) {});
})

Comment: As Andreas suggested an option is to use data attributes. Ex. <button class="btn" id="someButton" data-order-id="{{$order->id}}">Some text</button> And in js: $('#someButton').on('click', function () { var order_id = $(this).data('order-id'); });
})

Comment: @CalinBlaga this is the best solution for me. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
<button class="btn" id="someButton" data-order-id="{{$order->id}}">Some text</button>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#someButton').on('click', function() { 
    var order_id = $(this).data('order-id'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the variable you want to pass is global and applies go the whole page I would place it in a hidden input tag. Then retrieve the value when needed.

```
<input name=“globalValue” value=“{{ $value }}” type=“hidden”></input>
...
$(‘#someButton’).click(function(e) {
    var globalValue = $(‘input[name=“globalValue”’).val();
}
```

If the value is specific to the button then place it a `data-` attribute on the button.

```
<button id=“someButton” data-value=“{{ $value }}”>Some Button</button>
...
$(‘#someButton’).click(function(e) {
    var buttonValue = $(‘#someButton’).data(‘value’);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass global data in your jQuery function, then you can take that gloabal variable in hidden field like

```
<input type="hidden" id="gloabalVariable" value="{{$order->id }}">
```

And in your jQuery, you can get it by following line:

```
var orderId = $('#gloabalVariable').val();
```

Also you have mentioned that you dont want to use onClick event.
In this case, you can bind either `.click()` or `.mousedown()` event on your button.

Please let us know if you need further help regarding this.

Thanks